# Trusted Web Activity : TwaLauncher onDestroy() does not work

Tags: android, android-webview, trusted-web-activity

I want to close the Trusted web activity tab programmatically. I am trying the onDestroy method from twaLauncher but it does not work.

```
        twaLauncher = new TwaLauncher(activity);
        twaLauncher.launch( new TrustedWebActivityIntentBuilder(uri), null, null, null);

        final Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                twaLauncher.destroy();
                Toast.makeText(activity, " twaLauncher.destroy() called", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }, 5000);
```

Answer (score 1):

The Trusted Web Activity itself runs inside Chrome, that is, a different application than the one running TWALauncher. It's currently impossible to programmatically close it from the launcher app. The web page should be able to close it via `window.close()` (I haven't tested that, though).

Comment: Thanks for the response.
I tried windows.close() in the webpage it worked for me.